# Question regarding sets of measure zero.

Tags: real-analysis

If A is not of measure zero and if B is of measure zero, then what can we say about A intersection B set? 
Is it of measure zero or not of measure zero?

I know that a subset of set of measure zero is of measure zero.

How can this help me? 
Can I simply say that their intersection is of measure zero as it is subset of B? Then what can we conclude for the statement: A intersection B is subset of A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subset of a set of non-zero measure *may or may not be* of measure zero.

But Subset of a set of zero measure *must be* of zero measure.

So, This means, since $A \cap B$ is a subset of $B$ and hence, of measure zero.

Answer (score 1):

$A \cap B$ is a subset of $B$ and, as you said, it must have measure $0$. The fact that $A \cap B$ is also a subset of $A$ doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

If the measure is complete i.e. subset of every measure $0$ set is measurable then it must have measure $0$ as mentioned earlier by others. But if it is not complete then nothing can be said clearly.